# Reading of mtx file using scipy.io.mmread not working

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have several large .mtx (ranging from 2-12 GB) that I'm trying to load into a sparse matrix in Python, but it's not working. I generated the file myself without error on the same machine, so I'm completely baffled here.

Getting info on the file works fine:

```
from scipy.io import mminfo,mmread
mminfo(filename)
>>> (8649029, 181, 110656308, 'coordinate', 'real', 'general')
```

But if I try to load the file into memory:

```
mat = mmread(filename)
```

It just hangs. After an hour waiting, I tried interrupting the kernel (this was on IPython notebook on a Windows 7 machine), but this too would hang, and I had to shutdown the notebook to stop it. I repeated it from the command line, with similar results. This time I was able interrupt with ctrl-c, but got some sort of system error (no Python exception) I've never seen before:

```
forrtl: error (200): program aborting due to control-C event
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
kernel32.dll       0000000076CC4803  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
kernel32.dll       0000000076C8652D  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ntdll.dll          0000000076EBC541  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

I even tried loading the same file on a Mac through the Python interpreter. This too hung and could not be interrupted without shutting down my terminal session.

Any idea what might be happening here??

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similarly large files take a very long time for i/o in scipy. At the time, I  considered writing them as binary instead of the ASCII MTX format, which will reduce the amount of I/O required. See [Scipy I/O Cookbook](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/InputOutput#head-c963760a277e377035a59bc014b5070eb218125d), in particular the section titled "Write a Fortran or C array to a binary file with metadata". `libpny` will need to be linked in.